# Power Shell Script for permissions keeps overwriting previous script

Tags: windows, powershell

I have two very similar scripts for permissions and they keep overwriting each other.
When the two scripts grant permission to the same folder only Supervisor or Logistics group get it(the last script that i have executed.

## Supervisor.ps1

```
$dir = "E:\test\template\"
$acl = Get-Acl $dir
$permissions2 = 'Supervisors', 'ReadAndExecute,Write', 'ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow'
$permissions3 = 'Supervisors', 'ReadAndExecute', 'ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow'
$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList $permissions3
$acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
$acl | Set-Acl "$dir\01.Offers\02.Out\01.Main_Offer\02.Draft"
$acl | Set-Acl "$dir\01.Offers\02.Out\01.Main_Offer\03.Sent"
$acl | Set-Acl "$dir\01.Offers\02.Out\01.Main_Offer\04.Approved"
$acl | Set-Acl "$dir\01.Offers\02.Out\02.Additional_offers\01.Add_offer_1"
$acl | Set-Acl "$dir\02.Projects\01.Drawings"
$acl | Set-Acl "$dir\02.Projects\02.BoQ"
$acl | Set-Acl "$dir\03.Documents\01.Request_for_Offer"
$acl | Set-Acl "$dir\03.Documents\06.Other"
$acl | Set-Acl "$dir\04.Contracts"
$acl | Set-Acl "$dir\08.Logistics"

$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList $permissions2
$acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
$acl | Set-Acl "$dir\01.Offers\01.In"
$acl | Set-Acl "$dir\01.Offers\02.Out\01.Main_Offer\01.Calc"
$acl | Set-Acl "$dir\02.Projects\03.Reports"
$acl | Set-Acl "$dir\03.Documents\02.Schedules"
$acl | Set-Acl "$dir\03.Documents\03.Reports"
$acl | Set-Acl "$dir\03.Documents\04.Protocols"
$acl | Set-Acl "$dir\03.Documents\05.Construction_Programs"
$acl | Set-Acl "$dir\06.Correspondence"
$acl | Set-Acl "$dir\07.Pictures"
```

## Logistics.ps1

```
$dir = "E:\test\template"
$acl = Get-Acl $dir
$permissions = 'Logistics', 'ReadAndExecute,Write', 'ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow'
$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList $permissions
$acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
$acl | Set-Acl "$dir\01.Offers\01.In"
$acl | Set-Acl "$dir\01.Offers\02.Out\01.Main_Offer\01.Calc"
$acl | Set-Acl "$dir\02.Projects"
$acl | Set-Acl "$dir\03.Documents\04.Protocols"
$acl | Set-Acl "$dir\06.Correspondence"
$acl | Set-Acl "$dir\07.Pictures"
$acl | Set-Acl "$dir\08.Logistics"

$permissions1 = 'Logistics', 'ReadAndExecute', 'ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow'

$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList $permissions1
$acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
$acl | Set-Acl "$dir\01.Offers\02.Out\01.Main_Offer\04.Approved"
$acl | Set-Acl "$dir\01.Offers\02.Out\02.Additional_offers\01.Add_offer_1\03.Approved"
$acl | Set-Acl "$dir\03.Documents\02.Schedules"
$acl | Set-Acl "$dir\03.Documents\03.Reports"
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [AddAccessRule](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemsecurity.addaccessrule?view=netframework-4.8) instead of SetAccessRule?

The [SetAccessRule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemsecurity.setaccessrule?view=netframework-4.8) method adds the specified access control list (ACL) rule or overwrites any identical ACL rules that match the FileSystemRights value of the rule parameter.

Comment: Seems like nothing has changed :(